# On linux filesystem becoming RO, how to reliably reboot?

Tags: filesystems, cron, read-only

When the main Linux partition becomes `ro` for some reason (errors), I am trying to
use `cron` job to check and *reboot* (so that `fsck` can run and attempt a fix), but I see that even the `cron` may not run!

If, I detect that mount on `/` has become `ro`, what can I do to reliably
reboot a Linux host?

--
Thanks

--EDIT--

Details:
OS: Ubuntu (multiple versions - 18.04 et al)

FS: Ext4

script: is a simple `bash` script which is run via `cron` to check and do `reboot`

Comment: As filesystem is in RO mode any method of reboot is safe. Even pull the power cord.

Comment: That is not possible (the device does not have any operator closeby!) need to do it in some automated way

Comment: This site is for corporate systems. So your system is for example in datacenter so you can open service request to datacenter personnel to do it. Or your enterprise system have own service processor so you can login there from the interface power off/on the machine.

Comment: thanks @RomeoNinov but my question is more to understand if I can use `cron` or any other mechanisms to take a remedial action

Comment: You can try command `reboot`. But if it not work I explain you how you should proceed.

Comment: And reboot of course is not the answer to the problem: the cause (most probably hardware failure, or else, much more rare, kernel bug) has to be addressed, usually with money and new hardware.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the script you attempted, how it failed, what file system type, any disk errors perhaps from dmesg or log files, and which OS software distro. Linux could be almost anything; without more details any answers you get will not be specific.

Comment: Added more details

Comment: @RomeoNinov if `reboot` does not work, do you think using sysrq triggers to do reboot is guaranteed to work ?

Comment: You can try `echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger` but as I told you already the physical way will work 100%